# Mongodb aggregation: how to use unwind->group->project multiple times

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an orders collection where I need to calculate some sums from multiple sub-arrays arrays but I can't figure out how to loose the multiplied items that the double unwind creates.

```
db.Orders.aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$items"},
  {$unwind: "$shipping"},           
  {$group: {
    _id: {
      year: { '$year': '$createdAt' },
      month: { '$month': '$createdAt' },
      day: { '$dayOfMonth': '$createdAt' }
    },
    mainItems: { $addToSet: '$items' },
    totalSales: {$sum: {
      $multiply: ["$items.quantity",   "$items.variants.price"]
    }},
    averageSales: {$avg: {$multiply: ["$items.quantity", "$items.variants.price"]}},
    /* this will not sum the individial orders because the unwind 
     * created multiple document per order*/
    ordersPlaced: {$sum: 1}, 
    itemsPurchased: {$sum: "$items.quantity"},
    totalRefundAmount: {$sum: 0},
    chargedForShipping: {$sum: "$shipping.shipmentMethod.rate"}
  }}
)
```

If I take out the shipping from the unwind and the group the query will return the correct values except for the `chargedForShipping` (0 since it's `unwinded`) and `ordersPlaces` which will still be more than expected (but I also need the shipping information and even more additional ones that I took out for easier understanding).

Sample data:

```
[{
    "_id" : "xK29ZHxGcYvgWgx5p",
    "sessionId" : "yw7e9G7uBzYTy9Grq",
    "userId" : "fZREMm2DmsnMosMKj",
    "shopId" : "oiqQDnuBwabj44q2o",

    "billing" : [ 
        {
            "shopId" : "oiqQDnuBwabj44q2o",

            "_id" : "9TMJj9w65MmAkgg27",
            "paymentMethod" : {
                "amount" : 22.45,
                "status" : "settled",
                "mode" : "capture",
                "transactionId" : "AP",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T13:44:35.116Z"),
                "transactions" : [ 
                   { type:"refund", amount:5}
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {

            "shopId" : "9YfkXWyCci8fN43Pj",
            "_id" : "RwW8xMnFzQqdTpqtg",
            "paymentMethod" : {
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T13:44:35.116Z")
            }
        }, 
        {

            "shopId" : "SgXWPKGJkxBw6qsbT",
            "_id" : "ASizt6BtkxpCxgEJn",
            "paymentMethod" : {
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T13:44:35.116Z")
            }
        }
    ],
    "shipping" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "yXb5T5zLuxPYmgoT5",
            "shipmentMethod" : {
                "name" : "Continental US",
                "_id" : "womiJX2QZBFQQWFur",
                "rate" : 9.949999999999999,
                "shopId" : "9YfkXWyCci8fN43Pj",

            },
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "48s9bmDfrRMqnkije",
                    "productId" : "KXtF5xqERWJsXk2yP",
                    "shopId" : "SgXWPKGJkxBw6qsbT",
                    "variantId" : "YQDHuyPHbhx4wruZx",
                    "quantity" : 1
                }
            ],
            "packed" : false,
            "shipped" : false,
        }
    ],
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "hhuiGFTBkLACLpPjQ",
            "shopId" : "9YfkXWyCci8fN43Pj",
            "productId" : "sDYNXMrnRJiyQ8gex",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "variants" : {
                "_id" : "muJi6Bqnq2CD8B7AR",
                "price" : 2.5,
               "title" : "egy",
                "weight" : 23,

            },
            "type" : "simple",

        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "48s9bmDfrRMqnkije",
            "shopId" : "SgXWPKGJkxBw6qsbT",
            "productId" : "KXtF5xqERWJsXk2yP",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "variants" : {
                "_id" : "YQDHuyPHbhx4wruZx",
                "title" : "Bogi varinat title",
                "price" : 10,
                "type" : "variant",
                "compareAtPrice" : 100000,
                "weight" : 100,

            },
            "type" : "simple",

        }
    ],

    "email" : "test@user.com",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T13:44:35.091Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T14:24:55.174Z")
}]
```

What I would need is `orderTotal` per month, `shippingTotal` per month, `totalRefunded` per month, average sales per month. The issue is one I need from the items sub-array the other from the shipping sub-array and the third from the billing sub-array that is why I have issues with the unwind.

Comment: Are you able to post some sample data so that we can get an idea of what your document structure looks like? Also, can you give us what you are expecting your return to look like based off of the sample data?

Comment: If you look at this and consider carefully, the only thing that is really tripping you up here is the `mainItems` entry as a "set" of all items on that particular day. Most of the logic to get to the other result is fairly straightforward ( though with some tricks ). So ask yourself "do I really need that?". Without it the process is a lot more simplified, and arguably more performant as two separate queries if you really need the results. Not really seeing the value myself, but there may be a purpose.

Comment: I added the sample data in the original post.